# How to avoid running previously successful tasks in Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have multiple tasks that are passing some data objects to each other. In some tasks, if some condition is not met, I'm raising an exception. This leads to the failure of that task. When the next DAG run is triggered, the already successful task runs once again. I'm finding some way to avoid running the previously successful tasks and resume the DAG run from the failed task in the next DAG run.

Comment: How does it trigger the "already successful task" in the next dag run ? isn't it the Dag has its own set of tasks triggered on every run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, every DAG has it's set of tasks that are executed every run. In order to avoid running previously successful tasks, you could perform a check for an external variable via [Airflow XCOMs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) or [Airflow Variables](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#variables), you could also query the meta database as to the status of previous runs. You could also store a variable in something like Redis or a similar external database.

Using that variable you can then skip the execution of a Task and directly mark the task successful until it reaches the task that is to be completed.

Of course you need to be mindful of any potential race conditions if the DAG run times can overlap.

```
def task_1( **kwargs ):
    if external_variable:
        pass
    else:
        perform_task()
    return True
```